# Gradle: initwith don't work for minify and proGuard

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

In my code I have 5 build types. In my case, the QA one should initWith release, but this is not working, since when I run `./gradlew assembleQa` is not generating the mapping.txt

What I have try to far:

```
qa.initWith(buildTypes.release)
qa { 
    ... 
}
```

```
qa { 
    initwith release
    ... 
}
```

```
qa { 
    initwith buildTypes.release
    ... 
}
```

In all cases it won't get the property from release (since is not building the mapping)

```
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles 'proguard-android.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-log.pro'
```

So now I have this:

```
qa {
    ...
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles 'proguard-android.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-log.pro'
    ...
}

release {
    ...
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles 'proguard-android.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-log.pro'
    ...
}
```

What is not vert nice. How can I make initWith works? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides what I found in some Gradle courses, look like the order matter (at least inside the same function}

So, inside `buildTypes` to make **initWith** work it would need to come after. like this:

```
release {
    ...
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles 'proguard-android.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-log.pro'
    ...
}

qa {
    ...
    initWith buildTypes.release
    ...
}
```